# Does CockroachDB support full text search?

Tags: cockroachdb

I’m building an app on CockroachDB and need to do full-text search. Does CockroachDB provide that built-in?

Answer (score 5):

CockroachDB doesn't yet support full text search (which typically uses an inverted index). There are plans to add the feature in the future if there’s demand for it (you can chime in [here](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/7821)). In the meantime, consider integrating Lucene, Sphinx, or another search engine into your project.

Comment: Hi Peter, any recently developments on this front? Would be nice to have Apache Solr like full-text search. Right now, we have to front-end our app with a Apache Solr to provide search functionality.